# Theory by exercices.

Tags: reference-request

I learnt about Sylow group in a book that use a "Method from England" which is consist of to make a courses with exercices instead of exemples or proofs. (And of course the solution are in the end of the book !).

I understood the theory so easily with this book !

So I would like to do it again but I don't know any other books like this.

Can you help me to find some please ?

I study maths at the university since 4 years now. So the subjetct should be not too basic.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: If you are so much interested in Algebra, why not try books on Algebra by Herstein or Artin?

Comment: The whole of the Schaum's Outline series is somewhat like this.

Comment: Hi ! I like algebra, probability (I started stochastic process this years), analysis, measure theory (I really love it), ...

Comment: @ Aniruddha Deshmukh : Your book are very good thank you, but it is not the aim of the topic.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson : Thank you  ! This collection is huge, can you be more specific please.

Comment: You can probably tell from the title of each book, what the topic is, and whether it interests you. E.g., for probability, there's a Schaum's Outline of Probability and Statistics, a Schaum's Outline of Probability, Random Variables, and Random Processes, a Schaum's Outline of Probability – I have no way to know which one(s) will meet your needs. If the branch of math you're interested in is xxxx, just type Schaum's Outline xxxx into Google, and see what comes back.

Comment: Yeah I did that, thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary Number Theory by Joe Roberts is written entirely as a set of exercises with solutions. It also has the distinction of being done in calligraphy.

Comment: Thank you ! :).

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" the answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: I did thank you ;).